# Disable forced browsing from URL

Tags: angularjs, security, gulp

I do not know which components that would make preventing forced browsing.
I have an Angular app with gulp and currently I can browse file from url.

ex: http://localhost/foldername/file.js

I would like to prevent this and let user only access routes that I setup with $stateProvider.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
});  

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

My gulp setting is

```
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
connect.server = {
    livereload: true,
    root: ['app'],
    port: 8080
};
```

How can I prevent forced browsing ?

AngularJS: 1.4.9

gulp: 3.9.0

Comment: Use client side auth to block routes but critical part is server side to only serve data user has rights to

Comment: I omitted some other routes but most of routes does not require user to be logged in.  User can view contents but I don't want user to see my Javascript code directly.  Right now I can see it by accessing  http://localhost/foldername/file.js

Comment: no simple solution for that other than use programming language to populate script file  based on session authorization or something like that